# Building a REST API with Ruby/Sinatra and JRuby or Scala

Tags: ruby, api, scala, sinatra, jruby

I'm building a new REST API that will replace a pre-existing one. The older API was written to be a SOAP API built with Java and this is where the questions resides.
Most of the data access layer libraries are written in Java and if we could use those libraries would be a great asset.

Our two options so far are: **Ruby/Sinatra** and **Scala/Lift**

We also have the possibility to use **JRuby** on the Ruby/Sinatra stack in order to use the Java libraries that I mentioned before. Our main worry is in regards to possible JRuby-Java libraries incompatibilities...

What do you reckon is the best approach?

Comment: I've never used Scala/Lift but we have a REST API written with Ruby/Sinatra and it works great.  Very fast too.  Don't have a ton of experience running java libraries from ruby but I think it is pretty do-able even without JRuby if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, I think ruby would be a great option. However so much work has been put up on those Java Libraries and our timeframes are not ideal to take a leap of faith on this.

Comment: Sounds like Jruby may be the way to go:  http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2011/using-java-from-ruby-with-jruby-irb/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been using Ruby for the past 2 years, and recently tried to develop an application using Scala & Lift.

I gave up on Scala in favor of Ruby, and here's why.

The Ruby community is huge compared to Lift, you can get a gem basically for everything, there's tons of documentation and tutorials and it's easy to get a fast response when you run into trouble. The [Lift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lift) tag here on SO has only about 500 questions.

**Lift has a completely different approach to stuff**, and unless you already know Scala, it will give you a lot of pain before you get the hang of it.

On the other hand, **Sinatra is dead simple** and obvious. It's easy to integrate with other rack-based libraries and there's just tons of documentation and tutorials on Sinatra related issues.

I don't want to sound like I think Lift is bad, but it's definitely a lot more complicated to start with. Prototyping with Sinatra is also insanely easy, since you can drop everything into one file. Lift is a lot more heavyweight.

All this comes down is a matter of preferrence. If you're not afraid of Scala, give Lift a try. But if you just want to get the stuff done, Sinatra will give you much less headaches.

Comment: At this point we really need things done with as much less "unknown" as possible. Do you have any experience with JRuby?

Comment: @JoséP.Airosa only a little with my few contributions to http://redcareditor.com/ but I never really ran into any problems. Especially if you chose to use something as simple as Sinatra, it should be fairly easy to integrate with Java.

Comment: I really don't know the Ruby community, but the Lift community is very active, just not here on SO. For questions about Lift, you are better off asking on the [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb) where almost no answer goes unanswered.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking at Ruby/Sinatra you might want to consider [Scala/Scalatra](http://www.scalatra.org/) instead of lift as they are pretty similar. The advantage of scala here would be a really really great java interoperability
Another scala option to consider is [Finagle](http://twitter.github.com/finagle/) (my favorite) as it is field proven and geared towards hosting services (vs. web pages)

Comment: By the way - now there's also Finatra which provides Scalara semantics over a Finagle backend https://github.com/capotej/finatra (used by Zipkin http://twitter.github.com/zipkin/)

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you already picked an answer but just my 2 cents:
If you do want to try Lift, there is a lift REST example on the [wiki](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/REST_Web_Services) , another on the [Simply Lift book](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-5.4.html).

A more involved example that uses REST but also has a Comet based front end can be found on this [blog post](http://blog.fmpwizard.com/lift-comet-and-a-rest-api) (disclaimer: I wrote that post)